# Async update of array in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I have a view where I render tweets. Inside the tweets, there is the user_mentions array. From this array, I want to get one user, make another request to the API, get the avatar for the user and then render it. 
The view looks like:

```
<md-item ng-repeat="item in content">
  <div class="md-tile-left" ng-if="item.show">
     <img ng-src="{{item.thumb}}" class="face" alt="{{item.name}}">
  </div>
  <div class="md-tile-content">
     {{item.text}}
  </div>
</md-item>
```

*content* variable will contain all the tweets. Initially, content[i].show is false for all i. The controller code looks like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if(data[i].user_mentions[0]) {
     UserAvatar.get(data[i].user_mentions[0].screen_name).then(function(data){
        $scope.content[i].thumb = data.avatar;
        $scope.content[i].show = true;
     });
  }
}
```

Now, the problem I am facing is that after the UserAvatar service is called, variable *i* will continue to increment. So, by the time the callback is reached, i will have the value of data.length (hence, an error of undefined will be thrown). I have found a work-around by passing *i* to the API and then getting it back:

```
    UserAvatar.get(data[i].user_mentions[0].screen_name, i).then(function(data){
        $scope.content[i].thumb = data.avatar;
        $scope.content[i].show = true;
    });
```

**I realise that this is just a hack to make it work, but is there a more clever way of doing it?**

Comment: This is not an hack since getting the avatar is async process, so the i value will get increment. You can use async library also if it is becoming difficult for you

Comment: @MukeshAgarwal: Thank you! So you think that this is something that can be used in a production environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever a function is called you have to remember that when it's executed all the variables in the scope (not only `$scope` but also outer vars like i) created by an outer function will be visible to the function, I think you've already realized this, something important to realize is that you don't actually need `i` in the handler of `.then` you need to get the content at index `i` but how do you get rid of this dependency? I present two possible solutions:

1)

```
function getAvatar(name, contentToUpdate) {
  return UserAvatar.get(name)
      .then(function (data) {
        contentToUpdate.thumb = data.avatar;
        contentToUpdate.show = true;
      });
}

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if(data[i].user_mentions[0]) {
     getAvatar(data[i].user_mentions[0].screen_name, $scope.content[i]);
  }
}
```

When the handler of the `.then` function is called then the `i` dependency doesn't exist anymore

2)

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if(data[i].user_mentions[0]) {
     UserAvatar.get(data[i].user_mentions[0].screen_name).then((function(content) {
        return function (data) {
          content.thumb = data.avatar;
          content.show = true;
        }
     })($scope.content[i]));
  }
}
```

In this solution a IIFE returns a function which will be the handler, but the IIFE will actually catch the value of the content being analyzed, therefore when the inner function returned (which is the `onFulfilled` handler of `.then`) is called there's no `i` dependency

**Bonus:** One rule that has helped me a lot to deal with functions has been the following:

> A function will be executed in the place it was defined

I don't remember where I read it, I think it was in Nicholas Zakas' [Professional JavaScript for Web Developers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118026691), highly recommended :)

Comment: @MauricioPope: Thank you! I really like the second solution you provided.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your attempting to use closures inside a for loop which doesn't work as you've discovered. Your *hack* is one option to fix it. Another is to wrap your loop in a function either using `forEach()`/`map()` or an IIFE (`(function(i) { ... })(i);`).

In your example I'd do the following:

```
  var promises = data.map(function(item, index) {
     if (item.user_mentions[0]) {
        return UserAvatar.get(item.user_mentions[0].screen_name)
           .then(function(itemData) {
             $scope.content[index].thumb = itemData.avatar;
             $scope.content[index].show = true;
           });
     } else {
        return $q();
     }
  });
  $q.all(promises).then(function() {
     // All complete
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

> I realise that this is just a hack to make it work, but is there a
>   more clever way of doing it?

As @MukeshAgarwal said in his comment, this is not really a hack since `UserAvatar.get` is an asynchronous process.

Therefore, you have to *capture* the value of `i` at the moment of the asynchronous invocation.

The method you used is not that bad, but another method is to use an immediately invoked function :

This **does not work** :

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    // do something async
    setTimeout(function() { 
        console.log(i); // <- This will log 10 each time (the value of i at execution)
    }, 1000)

}
```

But **this works** :

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    (function() {      
        var j = i;   // <- The value of i is captured in j. j is in a closure
        // do something async
        setTimeout(function() { 
            console.log(j);  // <- This will log 0, then 1, then 2 ... then 9 
        }, 1000)
    })()

}
```